# Formulário enviado e exibição de outra pagina ao mesmo clique html

Tags: html, formulário, atributos

Olá, tenho um problema com a adaptação de um formulário. Achei questões similares no site, mas como sou iniciante em programação, talvez não tenha detectado a resposta para minha questão específica.

Tenho o seguinte formulário (não fui eu que montei, peguei pronto do plugin, e adaptei algumas coisas já):

```html
<div class="tnp tnp-subscription" style="margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%; padding: 1% 4% 4% 6%; border-width: px px  px px; box-shadow: 0px  0px  0px rgba(45,45,45,0.30); background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); display: block;"><form action="https://” method="post" name="nlang" type="hidden" value="" />
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-firstname" style="width: 98%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: -3%; display: inline-block;"><label></label><input class="tnp-firstname" name="nn" style="width: 99%;" required="" type="text" placeholder="Nome" /></div>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-email" style="width: 98%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: -3%; display: inline-block;"><label></label><input class="tnp-email" name="ne" style="width: 99%;" required="" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" /></div>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-privacy" style="margin-right: 25px; display: block; line-height: 1.4em;"><label style="text-align: left; font-family: Bitter; font-size: 10px;"><input class="tnp-privacy" name="ny" required="" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;<span style="font-family: Bitter; font-size: 15px; text-align: left;">Sim, ao informar meu e-mail, aceito receber conte&uacute;dos do blog e compreendo que posso me descadastrar a qualquer momento.</span></label></div>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-button"><input class="tnp-submit" style="width: 100%; background: #f6836b; color: #fff; font-size: 19px; border: 0px solid #d9534f; border-radius: 6px; font-family: , sans-serif;" type="submit" value="Envie para meu e-mail!"/></div>
</form></div>
```

Como podem ver, o atributo ***action*** está definindo o local de envio dos dados recolhidos do formulário, que leva a uma página padrão do plugin.
Mas na verdade, não quero que o usuário acesse essa página, quero que abra outra url para ele, ou que pelo menos ele seja automaticamente redirecionado para a pagina que eu quero após o envio do formulário.

> Resumindo, quero que no **único** clique, o formulário seja enviado, MAS a pagina exibida para o usuário seja outra.

Pesquisei sobre ações duplas no mesmo botão e também tentei redirecionamento dentro do próprio formulário, mas não estou conseguindo adaptar a minha necessidade.

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!

**ATUALIZAÇÃO DA PERGUNTA!**

Consegui abrir a url que quero em outra página com o código a baixo:

```html
<div class="tnp tnp-subscription" style="margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%; padding: 1% 4% 4% 6%; border-width: px px  px px; box-shadow: 0px  0px  0px rgba(45,45,45,0.30); background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); display: block;"><form action="https://enviaform" method="post" name="nlang" type="hidden" value="" onsubmit="myFunction()" />
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-firstname" style="width: 98%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: -3%; display: inline-block;"><label></label><input class="tnp-firstname" name="nn" style="width: 99%;" required="" type="text" placeholder="Nome" /></div>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-email" style="width: 98%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: -3%; display: inline-block;"><label></label><input class="tnp-email" name="ne" style="width: 99%;" required="" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" /></div>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-privacy" style="margin-right: 25px; display: block; line-height: 1.4em;"><label style="text-align: left; font-family: Bitter; font-size: 10px;"><input class="tnp-privacy" name="ny" required="" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;<span style="font-family: Bitter; font-size: 15px; text-align: left;">Sim, ao informar meu e-mail, aceito receber conte&uacute;dos do blog e compreendo que posso me descadastrar a qualquer momento.</span></label></div>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-button"><input class="tnp-submit" style="width: 100%; background: #f6836b; color: #fff; font-size: 19px; border: 0px solid #d9534f; border-radius: 6px; font-family: , sans-serif;" type="submit" value="Envie para meu e-mail!" /></div>
</form></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
window.open("https://google.com")
}
</script>
```

A página do action ainda abre, mas não tem mais problema.
O que acontece é que nos testes no w3schools funciona bem, ele abre as 2 url, mas quando apliquei na minha pagina, ela não roda o *myFunction()*.

O que está faltando?

Obrigada!

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi você precisa que o submit dos dados seja feito pela action do plugin, mas não seja redirecionado para o link da action? 
Se for este o caso você pode tentar o método preventDefault() do javascript

Comment: Se eu usar o preventDefault() ele ainda enviaria o formulário? Por que ele impedindo a abertura do url, impediria também o envio? E ainda assim, como eu faria para executar o meu outro link? No mesmo clique. Obrigada

Comment: Teria como usar uma function no atributo action? @CharlieSheen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou postar a qui o formulário que funcionou (sem o script), para ajudar a outros no futuro.

```html
<div class="tnp tnp-subscription" style="margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%; padding: 1% 4% 4% 6%; border-width: px px  px px; box-shadow: 0px  0px  0px rgba(45,45,45,0.30); background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); display: block;">    
<form action="https://enviaform" method="post" name="nlang" type="hidden" value="" onsubmit= window.open("https://pagina-de-destino") />
    <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-firstname" style="width: 98%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: -3%; display: inline-block;">
         <label>
         </label>
         <input class="tnp-firstname" name="nn" style="width: 99%;" required="" type="text" placeholder="Nome" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-email" style="width: 98%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: -3%; display: inline-block;">
     <label>
     </label>
     <input class="tnp-email" name="ne" style="width: 99%;" required="" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
    </div>
    
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-privacy" style="margin-right: 25px; display: block; line-height: 1.4em;">
    <label style="text-align: left; font-family: Bitter; font-size: 10px;">
      <input class="tnp-privacy" name="ny" required="" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;

  <span style="font-family: Bitter; color: #000000; font-size: 1/px; text-align: justified;">Sim, ao informar meu e-mail, aceito receber conteúdo do blog e compreendo que posso me descadastrar a qualquer momento.
  </span>
 </label>
</div>

<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-button">
    <input class="tnp-submit" style="width: 100%; background: #f6836b; color: #ffffff; font-size: 19px; border: 0px solid #d9534f; border-radius: 6px; font-family: , sans-serif;" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Realmente, para todos os profissionais que viram minha pergunta, pode ter parecido uma resposta muito simples, mas como disse, estou apenas começando e agradeço a quem se dispôs a me responder e me dar dicas.

Até mais!

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem a sua pergunta, você precisa submeter os dados para uma determinada rota porém, redirecionar o usuário para outra no sucesso da submissão, certo?

Caso sim, me parece o contexto adequado para o uso da [API XHR (XMLHttpRequest)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript).

- Primeiro atribua um identificador único (*id*) ao seu formulário para que possa referenciá-lo e obter os dados nele inseridos;
- Remova o atributo action do seu formulário, já que a requisição será feita em segundo plano, não precisamos definir o atributo explicitamente;
- Defina o método que irá realizar a submissão utilizando a API XHR e o atribua como ouvinte da submissão através do parâmetro *onsubmit*;

Ficaria algo nesse sentido:

```
<div class="tnp tnp-subscription" style="margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%; padding: 1% 4% 4% 6%; border-width: px px  px px; box-shadow: 0px  0px  0px rgba(45,45,45,0.30); background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); display: block;">

  <form id="myForm" method="post" name="nlang" type="hidden" value="" onsubmit="sendAndRedirect" />
    <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-firstname" style="width: 98%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: -3%; display: inline-block;">
      <label>
      </label>
      <input class="tnp-firstname" name="nn" style="width: 99%;" required="" type="text" placeholder="Nome" />
    </div>

    <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-email" style="width: 98%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: -3%; display: inline-block;">
      <label>
      </label>
      <input class="tnp-email" name="ne" style="width: 99%;" required="" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
    </div>

    <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-privacy" style="margin-right: 25px; display: block; line-height: 1.4em;">
      <label style="text-align: left; font-family: Bitter; font-size: 10px;">
        <input class="tnp-privacy" name="ny" required="" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;

        <span style="font-family: Bitter; font-size: 15px; text-align: left;">Sim, ao informar meu e-mail, aceito receber conte&uacute;dos do blog e compreendo que posso me descadastrar a qualquer momento.
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-button">
      <input class="tnp-submit" style="width: 100%; background: #f6836b; color: #fff; font-size: 19px; border: 0px solid #d9534f; border-radius: 6px; font-family: sans-serif;" type="submit" value="Envie para meu e-mail!" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  function sendAndRedirect() {
    var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        formData = new FormData(form);

    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
      location.href("https://google.com");
    });

    xhr.open('POST', 'https://enviaform');

    xhr.send(formData);
  }
</script>
```

Não depurei o código, porém provavelmente é o que você precisa.

Deixo pra você algumas dicas:

- Quando for iniciar uma pergunta, busque identar o código afim de melhorar a legibilidade e facilitar o entendimento, o que vai refletir em maior número de respostas;
- Dar uma lida no(s) link(s) de referência que deixei afim de entender realmente o que está sendo feito;

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigada!
Sua resposta funciona, porém meu plugin não aceitou o script e travou.
Tive que montar de outra forma, vou postar como uma resposta.

Obrigada pela atenção!!!